# Form submit or cancel submit after confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit

It is posible cancel form submit if i click Cancel?

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    confirm ("Are you ready?");
    $("#form")[0].submit();
});
```

Now any (after OK and Cancel) time form are submited.

I try this logicly should work.

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    confirm ($("#form")[0].submit(););
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) when you do not want form to get submitted.

```
$("#button").click(function(event){
    if(!confirm ("your message"))
       event.preventDefault();
});
```

[event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

> **Description**: If this method is called, the default action of the event
>   will not be triggered.

Answer (score 3):

Adding if should do for you

```
$("#button").click(function(){
if(confirm ("Are you ready?"))
    $("#form")[0].submit();
});
```